# NativeScript - Convert HTML string to HTML

Tags: html, mobile, nativescript

I use NativeScript to develop a mobile application. I have a **ListView** with **Label** and I want convert text with HTML to HTML.

[image]

I try to use `[innerHTML]` but it's doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the HTMLView Control. Check the details here in the below documentation.
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/html-view

Answer (score 1):

**Try** this

```
<HtmlView html="{{ htmlString }}"></HtmlView>
```

more info [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/html-view)